# function, range and symmetric difference

Tags: functions

$f(A)\triangle f(B) \subseteq f(A\triangle B)$. Is it true for all functions $f: (A\cup B) \rightarrow Y$? I think it is true but I can't prove it. Can you give me a hint, please? If there is $f(x)\in f(A)$, $f(x)\notin f(B)$ and $f(x)\in f(A\cap B) \Rightarrow f(x)\in f(B)$ because $f(A\cap B) \in f(B)$, so, $f(x) \in f(B)$. Contradiction. Is this a right solution?

Comment: Do you mean $f(A) = \{f(a)\mid a\in A\}$

Comment: What is the definition of $f(A \Delta B)$? What happens when you take an element $y \in f(A) \Delta f(B)$, is it contained in $f(A\Delta B)$?

Comment: Use the definition of symmetric difference: $\{f(a)\mid a\in A\} \triangle \{f(b)\mid b\in B)$.  Compare with $\{f(x) \mid (x\in A \land x\notin B) \lor (x \notin A \land x\in B)\}$